# How to execute a SQL query once a second 5 times, then output the result to the console each time

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a query and a datareader. How do I loop this for 5 times executing once a second then outputting the result to the console?
My query is returning just 1 column.

I tried using a while `dataread.read()` loop but was getting a "cannot convert between nvarchar and bigint" the column I'm returning is a nvarchar

```cs
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = strCmdText;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();

    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    int first = output.IndexOf("ID:");
    int last = output.IndexOf("To view");

    string between = output.Substring(first + 4, last - first - 5);
    int FullStop = between.IndexOf(".");
    string finalID = between.Remove(FullStop, 1);
                
    Console.WriteLine("Import started...");

    SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection1.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection1);
    SqlDataReader sqlDataReader;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("execution_id", finalID);

    sqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (sqlDataReader.Read())
    {
        string status = sqlDataReader[0].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(status);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No file found please try again");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: show us some code

Comment: Apologies @BagusTesa

Comment: Use a loop? A timer? If you only want to return a single value you can use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteReader`. There's no reason to convert the result to a string if you use `Console.WriteLine` either.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i would like to return just 1 string yes,

Comment: Did you try calling `command.ExecuteScalar` in a loop?

Comment: Yes but i keep getting this error on the while(sqldataReader.read) 

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.'

The column i want is not a bigint

Comment: It may be a computed column or a view. Without seeing the query and the table definition we cannot help. Side note: you must dispose your connection, command and reader with `using`.

Comment: SELECT  CASE [status] WHEN 1 THEN 'Created' WHEN 2 THEN 'Running' WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled' WHEN 4 THEN 'Failed' WHEN 5 THEN 'Pending' WHEN 6 THEN 'Ended Unexpectedly' WHEN 7 THEN 'Succeeded' WHEN 8 THEN 'Stopping' WHEN 9 THEN 'Completed' END AS StatusDesc FROM SSISDB.catalog.executions where execution_id = @execution_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in this code, I've assumed that the column you're retrieving from the database is of type NVARCHAR. If it's of a different type, you may need to use a different method to retrieve the data from the SqlDataReader (e.g. GetInt32, GetDateTime, etc.).

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading;

// ...

// Set up the SqlConnection and SqlCommand objects
string connectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True";
string query = "SELECT Column1 FROM MyTable WHERE ExecutionID = @execution_id";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@execution_id", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

// Execute the query 5 times with a delay of 1 second between each execution
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Import started...");

    // Open the connection and execute the command
    connection.Open();
    command.Parameters["@execution_id"].Value = "my_execution_id"; // Set the value of the parameter
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    // Read the data and output to the console
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string result = reader.GetString(0); // assuming the column is of type NVARCHAR
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    reader.Close();
    connection.Close();

    Thread.Sleep(1000); // Wait for 1 second
}
```

Comment: 1 more thing, is it possible to exit the loop when the result matches a certain string,

Comment: Yes, do this
while (reader.Read())
    {
        string result = reader.GetString(0); // assuming the column is of type NVARCHAR
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        
        if (result == "my_target_string")
        {
            // Exit the loop if the target string is found
            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Target string found. Exiting loop.");
            break;
        }
    }

Comment: the formatting is a bit messed up here could you edit your original answer please?